# Simulation failed in my firebase database rule

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my node Jason:

```
{
  "Users' Input History" : {
    "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" : {
      "-M-eylUaQcCpoyTLwbhk" : "fate"
    }
  },
  "Users' Vocabulary List" : {
    "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" : {
      "-M-eyxRLoCpDftWQ4cDn" : "hardliner"
    }
  }
}
```

This "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" is the uid for a user who can read and write his own value (here, it is "fate") under the "Users' Input History" node, and value (here, it is "hardliner") under the "Users' Vocabulary List" node.

This Jason will go on and on to have multiple users (uids) and their own multiple values. Each new user (uid) will populate under both the "Users' Input History" node and the "Users' Vocabulary List" node, and new values from that new user will populate under the new uid.

For example, I want user A (uid A) to able to read and write only his own values, and cannot read and write values from other users (uid B, C, D and so on), so I wrote my database rule like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
}
```

However, as in the image below, I'm getting this error saying Simulation failed at line 12: Expected '}'. Note that there's a red mark on line 12 and a ^ mark on line 13.
[image: Simulation with an error]

---

What I tried:
I added '}' right before "Users' Vocabulary List". That didn't work and then I added right before "$uid". Both led me to the same error message saying: Parse error. I don't know what else I can try. Is my rule wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested child for "Users' Vocabulary List" looks to be in the wrong place.  Move it up inside the "rules" object.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug. That solves the problem of failed simulation, but then an error comes up saying: Simulation for "read" has been refused. Should I worry about that?

Comment: If you have a new problem that's different than the first one, please post it separately to explain what isn't working the way you expect.